Visual Studio 2022, git revert hotkey
button highlighted
In Visual Studio 2022 Often I find myself discarding my changes one after the other, skipping some of them.
For that, I open the Git Changes window, double click on a changed file, and switch to keyboard.
F8 jumps to the next change. If I want to keep that change, I press F8 again to jump to the next one.
But if I want to discard the change, I need to get the mouse, click the revert button on the screenshot. I want a hotkey for that.
I have found Team.Git.Revert and Team.Git.RevertSelection commands, but they don't exactly do what I want, they remove only one line, after a confirmation question. The button on the screen does remove the whole change.
Can I assign hotkey to that button? Can I disable the confirmation question?
